# Open a jar file in a ansicon console through a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, jar, ansicon

I'm currently working on a new project. Since I use ANSI in this java project I realised I can't use these colors in a windows cmd.

I already tried various ways but none of them helped.

So, what do I want to do?
I want to run my jar file through a bat file in a new cmd but not the cmd from windows. I want to use the ansicon cmd ([ANSICON GitHub](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)).

So, I already tried this:

```
START ansicon.exe /k java -jar myjarfile.jar
```

But this doesn't worked at all.

I hope you can help me, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].  What exactly does "this doesn't work at all" actually mean?  What results did you expect and what did witness?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough.
I mean, when I start the bat file nothing happens.
It doesn't even open ansicon. I expected that ansicon opens and run the jar file.

Comment: What happens when you run `start ansicon.exe /k?`  What do you expect to happen? Does running `java -jar myjarfile.jar` work?

Comment: When I start ansicon and enter there `java -jar myjarfile.jar` it's working fine. But I want to open it through a bat file, so I want to open ansicon and send the `java -jar myjarfile.jar` command but this doesn't work because nothing happened.
When I use `start ansicon.exe /k?` nothing happens too.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I wasted your time. I found a solution. 
The following bat file is working fine:
`START ansicon.exe java -jar myjarfile.jar`

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with ansicon.exe. Just run ansicon.exe from a cmd prompt, what happens then?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Win10 console already support ansi escape sequences.

Comment: Typically using the start, you need to give a windows title, or no title.. i.e `start "" commandname parameters`

Comment: So it was the `/k` parameter that was the cause of the problem?

Comment: Yes, the `/k` parameter was the cause of the problem. It's working perfectly now, without the `/k`parameter. Thank you all.